# Caption below the figure and aligned with left side of figure

Tags: captions

How do I get my caption below the figure  and at the same time aligned with left side of my figure?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this one?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{slc=off} % "slc" is an abbreviation for "singlelinecheck"
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \captionbox
    {Blah... \label{fig:test}}
    {\includegraphics{test}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S.: The same effect can be archived using `\ffigbox` offered by the `floatrow` package, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow,caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{slc=off}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
    {\caption{Blah...}\label{test}}
    {\includegraphics{test}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

(For making `\captionsetup[figure]{slc=off}` work the `caption` package is needed here additionally.)

Comment: I'm guessing (since it isn't documented): `slc` is an alias for `singlelinecheck` (or the other way around)?

Comment: @cgnieder Yes, I was too lazy to write "singlelinecheck" all the time, therefore I introduced this abbreviation around 2008. BTW: Unfortunately `\captionbox` isn't documented yet, too, but its syntax is exactly the same as `\subcaptionbox` as explained in the `subcaption` package documentation. (Sorry for the documentation flaws, I already started to write a new and up-to-date documentation for the `caption` package bundle but progress is slow and my cats are demanding...