# When I use package floatrow, option skip of package caption doesn't work

Tags: spacing, floats, captions

Using this piece of code, I define a demo figure and its caption,

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
    \captionsetup{
        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{example-image-a}
        \caption{Caption goes here.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Now, according to Axel Sommerfeldt ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107350/caption-below-the-figure-and-aligned-with-left-side-of-figure)), I try to align caption with left side of figure. So, after modifying the above code, I write,

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}
    \captionsetup{
        slc=false
        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
        {\caption{Caption goes here.}}
        {\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And the output is pretty well. But I like to adjust the space between the figure and its caption. As the document of package `caption` says, option `skip` does it,

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}
    \captionsetup{
        slc=false,
        skip=2cm
        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
        {\caption{Caption goes here.}}
        {\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately option `skip` makes no difference, **unless I don't use package `floatrow`**. What is the problem cause? Something like incompatibility? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 4):

Use `\floatsetup{captionskip=…}`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}
    \captionsetup{
 slc=false,
 }

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\floatsetup{captionskip=2cm}
        \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
        {\caption{Caption goes here.}}
        {\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]